# Linking Flickr to Facebook

Tags: facebook, flickr

I'd like the photos I post on Flickr to be available on Facebook, ideally appearing as a status update on my wall. I tried linking my Flickr account to Facebook on the [extend tab](http://www.flickr.com/account?tab=extend) but the permissions asked are excessive (my friends profiles and so on...) so that one is out.

I tried [myflickr](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=2352557895&ref=search) but it does not work, giving a PHP error before doing the Flickr authorization.

I finally settled with [Flickr Tab](http://apps.facebook.com/flickrtab/) which is pretty good but only adds an extra tab on my profile, and does not publish anything when I upload a new photo on Facebook.

So, what do you use to connect your Flickr account to Facebook?

---

Here are the permissions I am asked to give while linking my accounts:

**Access my basic information**

Includes name, profile picture, gender, networks, user ID, list of friends and any other information I've shared with everyone.

**Access Facebook Chat**

**Access my Profile information**

Likes, music, TV, movies, books, quotes, About me, Activities, Interests, Groups, Events, Birthday, Religious and political views, Education history, Work history and Facebook status

**Access my contact information**

Current location

**Access my friends' information**

Birthdays, Current locations, Education history, Work history, Events and Facebook statuses

I can understand why it needs my basic information, but the others seems downright excessive to me!

Chat?? My friends' info ?? Why?

Comment: Why do you think the permissions are excessive? I doubt they are. Plus, at least Flickr's from a trust worthy company like Yahoo. It's not one of those spam games which ask you for access to your profile?

Comment: could you list the permission problems you are having? , flickr-facebook connection is the best thing to happen imho. Maybe you can file a feature request to Flickr's Dev Team.

Comment: I really would suggest sticking with the extend tab option - it really does work really well.

Comment: ok I see what you mean now. This just how Yahoo has it set up. It is basically a take all or take none of it since pulse,flickr and other services use the same setup. I would say to look through their app list http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/search/?q=facebook&sort=interesting

Answer (score 2):

I have a FriendFeed account that is connected to my flickr account and I have installed [friendfeed app](http://apps.facebook.com/friendfeed/) in Facebook.
So when I upload to Flickr it shows in my FriendFeed which then posts to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic but the problem is still around: [Flickoutr](http://clientsideweb.net/social/flickoutr) only asks for the permissions it needs to accomplish sharing, ie offline publishing together with the default Facebook app permissions. Also unlike Flickr it alerts you when you need to re-authenticate with Facebook and gives you a simple URL to click to enable you to do so.

It also allows you to share by set or group. Premium accounts support more frequent blogging, Flickr group sharing to Facebook groups/pages and support for multiple Flickr accounts.

Disclosure: I'm the programmer.